# Finding squares in finite fields

Tags: finite-fields

I need the definition of finding squares in finite fields and also the number of squares in a  finite field. How can we find squares in $\Bbb F_5$ and $\Bbb F_7$? (Here $\Bbb F_5$ and $\Bbb F_7$ indicate the finite fields for $q=5$ and $q=7$ respectively.)

Can we generalize for different values of $q$? I need your help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** In a field with characteristic different from $2$, if $a\ne 0$ the equation $x^2=a$ has $0$ or $2$ solutions.

If you are interested in finding the squares in a field with $5$ elements, or one with $7$, you know what thse fields look like, square each element and list the answers you get.

Comment: i am sorry but how can i use this hint?

Comment: I will give a further related hint. Of course $0$ is a square. Let $F^\ast$ be the non-zero elements of your field. Consider the function $\varphi: F^\ast\to F^\ast$ defined by $\varphi(x)=x^2$. This is a "two-to-one" function. How many values are in its *range*?

Answer (score 0):

If $F_n$ is a finite field where $n$ is an odd prime, then the perfect squares in $F_n$ are namely the quadratic residues $\pmod n$. For example, in $F_5$, $1$ and $4$ are the only non-zero elements which are perfect squares, because $1^2 = 1, 2^2 = 4, 3^2 = 4, 4^2 = 1$. Answer made simple.